# Healthy blueberry plant dropping flowers

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, blueberries

[image: green blueberry plant]

My blueberry plant (pink lemonade) has been dropping flowers a week after I hand pollinated them. I only have one plant. Can anyone tell me why? It looks pretty healthy so I’m not sure what’s going on.